# Is it safe for my cat to carry/jump around with heavy toys in her mouth?

Tags: cats, safety, play, toys

I got this automated toy for my cats:

[https://www.amazon.com/SmartyKat-Hot-Pursuit-Concealed-Motion/dp/B06WP7F8YC](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B06WP7F8YC)

My female cat really, really likes the toy. She grabs onto it and carries it around, even jumping on top of her cat tree with it held in her mouth, carrying the large base by the long "tail" moving piece.

However, she is a fairly small cat, about 9 lbs, and the toy with batteries is about 3 lbs. She moves slowly while dragging it; I'm quite surprised she was able to jump with it. I'm afraid she will hurt her neck. Am I right to be concerned, or are cats used to dragging around prey that heavy?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Yes, it's safe.

The prey cats feed on can be up to their own weight, or so says [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cat#Hunting_and_feeding). While dragging might go slow with heavy weights, they can do it. Same with jumping.

Comment: my cat did steal doormats when i got her,she dragged the mat thru the hallway and then the kitchen and livingroom and into the bedroom.this was a thick rubberized doormat it was heavier than my cat so yes cats are strong.

Comment: Slippers bringing a duck through the cat flap! https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=G3-sie5pNUE